# Should I use "will" or "would" in "election that would/will take place in 2018"?

Tags: future-tense, will-would

> *After having drunk seven beers, he announced his candidature in the presidential election that **would**/**will** take place in 2018.*

I am not sure whether to use "will" or "would". The main clause is in the past but there is referred to the future so I am leaning towards "would". Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express this as a narrative with its  center of conscious  (or temporal *origo*) being the inebriated politician as he looked forward to the election:

> After having drunk seven beers, he announced his candidature in the
>   presidential election that would take place in 2018.

or as reportage told from the perspective of the reporter and the readership in their shared present:

> After having drunk seven beers, he announced his candidature in the
>   presidential election that will take place in 2018.

Comment: To tell the truth I am not sure that I understand your explanation of the usage of "would" (what is temporal origo?). Could you be please a little bit dumped down.

Comment: Have you looked up *origo*?

Comment: A fine point, but "candidacy" is more commonly used in American English than "candidature."

Answer (score 0):

This is the past future. You are describing something in the past, and referring to something that is in the future at that point in time.

<strike>In your case, the word "Will" is correct. This is because 2018 hasn't happened yet.</strike> Either word can be correct. See [Tᴚoɯɐuo](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/10264/t%e1%b4%9ao%c9%af%c9%90uo)'s answer.

You would use the word "would" when you are describing something that was in the future at that point in time, but has passed since then.

Examples:

> Last September we decided that we would meet again at christmas.
>
> Last September we decided that we will meet again at christmas.

The first sentence is referring a christmas which *was* in the future, but is now in the past. The second sentence is referring to a christmas which is *still* in the future.